# Read Certain Data from text File

Tags: c#, text-files

```
586 21.6.2018 51 2 85 555 2
384 9.4.2016 51 13 7 910 1
49 12.8.2016 91 4 76 769 2
782 2.5.2018 59 7 73 144 1
573 6.3.2017 14 10 73 591 2
```

**I have a Text File which includes these data types , they are separated with one space , What i need to do is that . For an example reading date data type(21.6.2018,9.4.2016,12.8.2016 ...) for all these 5 lines or reading numbers till the DATE data type . When I am reading these lines , i need to do it for the all 5 lines so not only 1 line . I am little bit confused how to do it.**

(I have 25 lines of these data types but i tought writing 5 of them would be enough)

**Any guidance would be appreciated**

Comment: How do you do it for one line? Do you know about [iteration statemens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/iteration-statements)?

Comment: Yes i do , i was also thinking like doing with 'String Split' but i really dont know how to sort these data types

Comment: Sort? You didn't mention any sorting in your question. If you have written some code, you should definitely include it in the question, to show your effort. Otherwise, you are asking busy people to solve your entire problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex with LINQ to compare the Date format data type.

### CODE

```
// Regex pattern to match DD.MM.YYYY Format
var regexPattern = @"^([0]?[0-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])[.]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[.]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$";
Regex regexObj = new Regex(regexPattern);
// Matched Values matching the regex pattern are returned in IENUMERABLE OF STRING TYPE 
var dates = File.ReadLines(txtFilePath).Select(lines => lines.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(colValue => regexObj.IsMatch(colValue)));
```

Comment: How can i pass values to the List<string> in var dates ? Because I need to do mathematical calculations in dates , like adding 2 months to one date or extracting the date

Comment: // Converting the List<string> to List<DatetTme> object and once you get the Date time object you can do mathematical calculations on month or year using inbuilt add days or months.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
**List<DateTime> dates = strings.Select(date => DateTime.Parse(date)).ToList();**

Comment: Modified the code                                                                                                                **List<DateTime> dates = strings.Select(date => DateTime.ParseExact(date,"dd.MM.yyyy",null)).ToList();**

Comment: I am having System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' Error
List<DateTime> datesList = dates.Select(date => DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", null)).ToList();


// dates.Select(this dates variable is the one you posted (var dates)

Comment: //Updated the DateFormat type used **d.M.yyyy** format                                                                                                            
**List<DateTime> dates = strings.Select(date => DateTime.ParseExact(date,"d.M.yyyy",null)).ToList();**

Comment: @MertcanBayraktar you got any issue while running the mentioned code.

Comment: All perfect , thanks for help but only thing i wonder is that in console date looks in this format dd/mm/yyyy but in my text file actually date in this format dd.mm.yyyy i didnt understand why it is changed tho

Answer (score 2):

This code will read all lines and put all the dates in the `dates` list:

```
var dates = File.ReadLines("<path to your file>")
    .Select(line => line.Split(' ')
             .Select(column => DateTime.TryParseExact(
                          column, 
                          "d.M.yyyy", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out var date)
                        ? (DateTime?)date : null))
             .Where(c => c != null)
             .First());
```

Another version that creates anymous objects of the entire rows:

```
var dataRows = File.ReadLines("<path to your file>")
        .Select(line => {
                 var strings = line.Split(' ');
                 return new { Col1 = int.Parse(strings[0]),
                          Col2 = DateTime.ParseExact(
                              strings[1],
                              "d.M.yyyy", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                          Col3 = int.Parse(strings[2]),
                          Col4 = int.Parse(strings[3]),
                          Col5 = int.Parse(strings[4]),
                          Col6 = int.Parse(strings[5]),
                          Col7 = int.Parse(strings[6])
                 };
               });
```

Of course you may create a class of your own and use that instead of the anonymous return. The names `Col1...Col7` may be renamed to something that makes more sense in your use case.

To output all rows you need to use a loop:

```
foreach(var row in dataRows)
{
     Console.WriteLine(row.Col1);
     Console.WriteLine(row.Col2);
     Console.WriteLine(row.Col3);
     Console.WriteLine(row.Col4);
     Console.WriteLine(row.Col5);
     Console.WriteLine(row.Col6);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Only thing is that when i try to console write Col2 ,it returns only the first line's value not the rest

Comment: Added a loop for outputting all rows.